# Text/HTML wrap fails to wrap when calling JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, swing, user-interface, word-wrap

I have am using JEditorPane to display some text that contain the HTML tag,

```
JEditorPane htmlTextPane = new JEditorPane();
htmlTextPane.setContentType("text/html");
htmlTextPane.setText("This text pane contains html. The custom HTMLEditorKit supports single letter wrapping."); 
final JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(htmlTextPane);
editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
editorScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

[image]

When I start the application, the `text/html` seems to wrap properly, but when I try to set the value of the `JEditorPane` in runtime (for example click a table row, that get the `html` text) by calling `JEditorPane.setText("some html text")`, the new text fails to wrap and I do not see the whole text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this should work, but it may fail for some specific HTML snippet. 
In such a case a rewrite of HtmlEditorKit.HTMLFactory is needed.
You can set an enhanced EditorKit by

```
htmlTextPane.setEditorKit(anEnhancedHtmlEditorKit);
```

Please provide sample HTML which fails.

Comment: <td><font style="font-size:10pt; font-family:arial, sans-serif; color:#000"><strong>Dear,</strong><br /><br />Hi, I'm referring to the pin that goes into the phone. The charger seems to work fine in a different phone that I own, so perhaps it's a problem with the phone!<br /><br />
  <div style="font-weight:bold; font-size:10pt; font-family:arial, sans-serif; color:#000">
   - mikohayle
  </div></font></td>

Comment: It is related to this specific incomplete HTML table, in case you will wrap it to the tr or table tag, or if you remove the td tag, it will behave correctly.

Comment: Hi @MirecXP, thank you so much, I added the <tr> tags around the HTML text and it worked.